# How do I stop HTMLWriter from writing bad HTML? (using HTMLEditorKit)

Tags: java, htmleditorkit, htmlwriter

Here is surprising behaviour.  I create a JTextPane , set it up to use HTMLEditorKit, and fill it with valid HTML.  But by default Java's HTMLWriter creates ***invalid*** HTML. Most items are serialised out correctly but img tags lose their closing slash so :

```
<img src="https://localhost:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.IImageContentService/processattachment/_7rfpIMXdEeGLRroh_7O2yQ/workflow/resolve.gif" alt="Resolved" border="0"/>
```

is written as :

```
<img src="https://localhost:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.IImageContentService/processattachment/_7rfpIMXdEeGLRroh_7O2yQ/workflow/resolve.gif" alt="Resolved" border="0">
```

I'm using defaults for everything. Why does it not work, is there any easy fix?

Here is a code snippet:

```
    JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
    HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    editor.setContentType("text/html");
    editor.setEditorKit(htmlKit);   
    editor.setText( '*<ADD SOME VALID HTML FROM A FILE>*'  );       
    HTMLDocument d = (HTMLDocument)editor.getDocument();
    StringWriter fw = new StringWriter();
    HTMLWriter aHTMLWriter = new HTMLWriter(fw,d);
    aHTMLWriter.write();
    String txt = fw.toString();
    //  Now  txt is not valid HTML ... eek!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is valid HTML, but it's not valid XHTML. As far as I know it's not possible to get it to output XHTML. You could post-process the output using regular expressions, or extend HTMLWriter like Freeplane did when they wrote [XHTMLWriter](http://freeplane.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.3-1/XHTMLWriter_8java_source.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the HTMLEditorKit only supports HTML 3.2, and for that the img tags should not be closed . So it is behaving "correctly".

[A Request for enhancement](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4296022) was issued 1999, so maybe it will be implemented soon.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes,  I'd clean forgotten about how historic HTML 3.2 worked (past tense.)  The history of the 'request for enhancement' makes very sad reading . . .